# Loooking for name of this geometrical optimization technique

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

From my knowledge if you fit geometrical objects into point clouds you want in general minimize the squared distances of the point cloud to your fitted objects. I do so with the downhill simplex method by minimizing the average squared distance. I fit cylinders. In rare input scenarios I end up having not good fitted cylinders - detected by visual validation. Those cylinders have one thing in common. Their axis is not perpendicular to the points's normals. I can modify my error term by multiplying the squared distance of a point to a cylinder with the cosinus of the angle between the point's normal and the cylinder axis. This cosinus is 1 in the worst case and 0 in the best case.

I am looking for a name of this technique and/or publications. I think the most generic formualtion of what I am doing would be:

Modify the squared euclidean distance between input and output accounting to a change in curvature.

Comment: Do you mean that in your data the points have specified normals ? In that case, you may add to your objective function the deviation between the datapoint's normal and the cylinder's nearest point normal (probably times a scaling factor that you need to make independent on the object's size).

Comment: @brunoLevy I compute for my 3D cloud before the optimization the normals with standard technique. Range search to retrieve a local neighborhood cluster, perform PCA and take the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue. I also have the axis and can compute the described cosinus/angle. My question is more about how this technique is called (I just assume I reinvented the wheel today) to be able to find some references to a) improve the technique and b) give a proper citation.

Comment: There are two papers that could be interesting: the first one (variational shape approximation), with what you need (maybe L1,2 norm) http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/CAD04.pdf The second one combines positions and normals for reconstructing shapes: http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Nehab_2005_ECP/

Comment: Do you mean the "Nelder-Mead" Simplex method? That horrendous algorithm should have been put out of its misery several decades ago.

Comment: Are you refering to Iterative Closest Point by Besl and McKay (1992), "A Method for Registration of 3-D Shapes" ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is a good parameterization of cylinder, as well as a fast scheme for performing gradient descent minimization, similar to [iterative closest point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point).

While many papers are available, I would redirect you to [this particular one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7335508/):

> Drost, Bertram, and Slobodan Ilic. "Local Hough Transform for 3D Primitive Detection." *3D Vision (3DV), 2015 International Conference on. IEEE, 2015.*

There, authors devise a scheme for detection, as well as refinement of the cylinders, with a new parameterization. The approach doesn't use the point normals, however I believe that such a treat would be appropriate. Yet, it is found to be effective enough, when one uses a *point-to-primitive* distance.

I'm sure you'll find it useful.